# Error: redirect_uri_mismatch (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-api, google-oauth, google-signin

I am getting the following error when trying to let user login using GOOGLE

[image]

I have tried so many things and nothing works

I used the following code initially

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(clientId: "APIKEY.apps.googleusercontent.com",
            clientSecret: "SECRET-K");
```

I also tried the following

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
            {
                ClientId = "APIKEY.apps.googleusercontent.com",
                ClientSecret = "SECRET-K",
                CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-google")
            });
```

No luck at all,

My Client ID for Web application is set up as following
[image]

I have no idea what i am doing wrong,

Have anyone faced this issue and have a solution for this

Highly appreciated

Cheers

Comment: in Google developer console remove the / at the end of your redirect URI.   Might help https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-aspnet-mvc

Comment: WOW - That worked, thank you so much @DaImTo how do i mark this question as ANSWERED?

Comment: Last week some guy had added a , on the end your not the only one to do this :)

Comment: @DaImTo makes me feel a little bit better hahahhahah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google developer console remove the **/** at the end of your redirect URI.

Redirect URI must match exactly the location you are sending it from.